# Reindex without changing order

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DataFrame:

```
in  year   ni  d  m   x    y        q
1   2012   1   2  0  NaN  NaN       3
6   2012   2   1  1    9    9       1
5   2012   3   1  1   17   17       1
3   2012   4   0  3   37   37       0
5   2012   5   1  0  NaN  NaN       3
2   2012   6   3  1   15   15       3
```

When I use df.reindex(index=[1,2,3,4,5,6]) - basically column 'ni' (the index I want to use) - then this will change the order of my dataframe, which I try to avoid. I know I can do it with rename, but the data has 5,0000 rows and it's quite weary writing such a dictionary...

So is there a way to remain the order but change the index or is there a trick to do a quicker rename or simply adapt ni as the index?

Comment: Is df.set_index("ni") solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your DataFrame is as follows (with index `'in'`), you can use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
In [1]: df = pd.read_csv('ni.csv', sep='\s+', index_col=0)

In [2]: df
Out[2]: 
    year  ni  d  m   x   y  q
in                           
1   2012   1  2  0 NaN NaN  3
6   2012   2  1  1   9   9  1
5   2012   3  1  1  17  17  1
3   2012   4  0  3  37  37  0
5   2012   5  1  0 NaN NaN  3
2   2012   6  3  1  15  15  3

In [3]: df.set_index('ni', drop=False)
Out[3]: 
    year  ni  d  m   x   y  q
ni                           
1   2012   1  2  0 NaN NaN  3
2   2012   2  1  1   9   9  1
3   2012   3  1  1  17  17  1
4   2012   4  0  3  37  37  0
5   2012   5  1  0 NaN NaN  3
6   2012   6  3  1  15  15  3
```

Although this is probably ok in many cases, if you are concerned about speed and memory usage you can do this `inplace` (i.e. change `df` without creating a copy).

```
In [4]: df.set_index('ni', drop=False, inplace=True)
```

*`inplace` seems to be around 30% faster.*

Comment: Thx alot, for some reason I wasn't aware of that one!